# Use in android:layout_weight buttons Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I try to put buttons on screen. I want that this screens be split in same space on whole screen. I read a lot of the answers about use in android:layout_weight but i didn't get success.

**code:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/p_data_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/p_selector"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/p1_data_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/p1_selector"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/p2_data_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/p2_selector"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/p3_data_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/p3_selector"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

***EDIT:***

This background work with selector. it is affected?

I add Answer.

Comment: what's your problem your code is splitting screen in 4 same parts.

Comment: Are your drawables of different size? It might cause a problem

Comment: I hope that.. this code split the buttons in same parts but is not all the screen. this buttons display only on top screen.

Comment: @ AReader you are right he must use diff size drawables..otherwise his code seems to be perfect.

Comment: the drawables are on same size

Comment: Strange. I tried your code in a sample app. giving me perfect result in layout

Comment: @blay i have tested your code it is displaying 4 buttons having same size covering whole screen.

Comment: Yes, is this all xml code. You right that 4 buttons having same size covering whole screen but its didn't work for me...

Comment: @blay what is the output in your device?and also try to remove background attribute and then try.

Comment: I try to remove the background. but is the same problem.

Comment: It is working here too! Please send a screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code which split screen textviews in 5 parts on screen.. in your code you havent provided android:weightSum="5" property..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/l"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUHID"
        style="@style/pateint_context_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="UHID: " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtBedID"
        style="@style/pateint_context_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Bed ID: "
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDOB"
        style="@style/pateint_context_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="DOB: " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSex"
        style="@style/pateint_context_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Sex: " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAge"
        style="@style/pateint_context_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Age: " />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks. I try this but it don't work. Also i reas that this attribute is not biding

Comment: try this, remove  android:layout_gravity="center" i think your all buttons stacked up on each other.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_height="match_parent"` if you are using weights and you want for the elements to cover the entire space.

Answer (score 0):

As the Button are of size "wrap_content". They aren't showing.

Just place some text  `android:text="test"` in the all button. **It would work**. *Else use image in background selector.*

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem . You all right. The code work fine. In the old version of this application they do function that in some case put all content in relative layout. I understood that when content is in relative layout its need to be put on linear layout. but it's Ddon't working..

I convinced after i replace this function that this was what cause to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml code is absolutely fine, and it should display what you want it to display.
There must be something wrong with the drawable background you have added to all the buttons. I suggest that you remove the drawable and apply some basic color like

`android:background="@color/black"`

to make sure that it's problem with the drawable. Good luck!